# Data Adapter Filter

Tags: c#, winforms, tableadapter

I'm using the wizards etc to create a c# form based application that uses a database for storage etc.

I have a customer form that currently lists all records in a datagrid.

```
private void frm_customer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.tbl_customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.myDataSet.tbl_customer);
}
```

I'm hoping to filter the records.

After reading some other topics I've discovered that a Select method may be used to filter my TableAdapter. So far I have the following attached to a button.

```
string qString = "cust_postcode = CF48 4JY";
string oString = "cust_postcode DESC";
myDataSet.tbl_customer.Select(qString, oString);
```

When I hit the button it throws the following error;

"Syntax error: Missing operand after '4' operator."

I'm aware that the problem is to do with the qString itself, however I can't seem to find the correct way to do the query.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string qString = "cust_postcode = 'CF48 4JY'";
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I may of fell asleep at the computer again.

Apologies for the late reply! I can't believe I didn't spot it.